# Python Sqlalchemy most efficient way to load many to many relation data into view

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table `User`.

I have a table `Post`.

A user can create multiple posts, which are saved in the `Post` table.

Users can follow each other. This relationship is stored in a many to many table `UserFollowUser`.

```
class UserFollowUser(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'userfollowsuser'
    user_id_follower_from = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    user_id_follower_to = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'), primary_key=True)
    date_added = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)  

class User(UserMixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(Text, nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    date_registered = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    # Foreign Keys
    belongs_to_user_addresses = relationship('Post', back_populates="belongs_to_user_relation")
    # Foreign Keys for many to many follow
    user_to = relationship('UserFollowUser', backref='to_user', primaryjoin=id==UserFollowUser.user_id_follower_to)
    user_from = relationship('UserFollowUser', backref='from_user', primaryjoin=id==UserFollowUser.user_id_follower_from )
    # etc ...

class Post(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'posts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    description = Column(Text, nullable=True)
    created_on = Column(DateTime, nullable=False)
    hidden_post = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=False)
    # Foreign Keys
    created_by_user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('users.id'))
    belongs_to_user_relation = relationship("User", back_populates="belongs_to_user_addresses")
```

Adding data to all tables works great.

Now I want to display the posts of users, which a certain user follows to. So its a classical timeline.

I have a working approach, but I do not use the relation while I get the data as I usually do. I simply join `Post` with `UserFollowUser` and filter by `current_user` (The timeline is displayed on the profile).

```
posts_timeline = Post.query.join(UserFollowUser, UserFollowUser.user_id_follower_to == Post.created_by_user_id).filter_by(user_id_follower_from=current_user.id).order_by(desc("created_on")).all()
```

In view:

```
{% for post in posts_timeline %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 text-center">
        <div class="post-item">
            <h2> {{ post.title }} </h2>
            <p> {{ post.description }} </p>
            <p> {{ post.created_by_user_id }} </p>
            <p> {{ post.created_on }} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

It works, but is it the best way to do it? I want to know whether this is best practise, as loading a timeline could lead to performance issues.

Comment: You can increase the log level of SQLAlchemy so that it logs the actual SQL being rendered/sent to the DB. You can then run the same sql on you DB with explain on, and then you can look at the query plan to decide if the DB is doing what you expect/want it to be doing.